# Prove that a tree with two vertices of degrees $k$ and $l$ has at least $k + l - 2$ leaves

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

> Let there be a tree with at least two vertices. One vertex has degree
>   $k$ and the other has degree $l$.  Prove that such tree has at least
>   $k + l - 2$ leaves.

My logic is that from one vertex you can reach at least $k$ leaves and from the other vertex you can reach at least $l$ leaves. But how exactly would I prove that you have to subtract $2$? Is it because if you start from one of the given vertices and go through the second one, then one of the leaves will be a duplicate?

Comment: If you start from one of the vertices and follow a path of vertices to the second, you have discovered a cycle.  And cycles are not allowed in trees.

Answer (score 2):

In the tree $T$ there's a path from the vertex $v$ of degree $k$ to the
vertex $w$ of degree $l$. Let this path start with the edge $e$. There are
$k-1$ other edges from $v$, and one can walk from $v$ starting at any of
these edges and reach a leaf. This accounts for $k-1$ leaves. Likewise
start at $w$ to reach $l-1$ further leaves.

Comment: A relevant (I think) addition is that the path from $v$ to $w$ is *unique* in a tree.  So OP's concern about following a branch along an edge other than $e$ from $v$ and accidentally ending up at $w$ won't happen.